# Como remover underscore de un archivo

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un archivo que tiene la convension de nombre siguiente:

**TestClases_20200209_050001.csv**

Lo que quiero es solamente dejar este nombre.

**TestClases.csv**

Son archivos con diferentes nombres, pero el timestamp va a siempre ser parte del nombre.

Como podria hacer esto?

Esto es el codigo en **c#** que tengo hasta el momento pero solo me remueve el ultimo underscore:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp", "*.csv");
foreach (string file in files)
{
    int underscoreIndex = file.LastIndexOf("_");
    int dotIndex = file.LastIndexOf(".");

    string newFilename = file.Substring(0, underscoreIndex);
    newFilename += file.Substring(dotIndex);


    switch (newFilename)
    {
        case "TestClases":
            GetLatestFile();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }                
}
```

Comment: separalos por cada "_" en un array siempre tomas el item 0 del array ese siempre sera el nombre y los otros dos item seran las numeros. :)

Comment: utiliza split en vez de substring

Comment: te dejo este link con algunos ejemplos de como utilizar split. https://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible utilizar la funcion split, pero primero es necesario solo obtener la parte del nombre con la funcion "GetFileName" por si usas un directorio con underscores.
Despues puede utilizar la funcion split y linq de la siguiente manera para lograr lo que necesitas:

```
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp", "*.csv");
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            //Obtenemos el directorio de la ruta
            string directory=System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
            //obtenemos la primera parte del nombre
            string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file).Split('_').First();
            //Le pegamos la extension
            name+= "." + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file).Split('.').Last();
            //finalmente combinamos el directorio y el nombre
            string newFilename = directory + "\\" + name;

            switch (newFilename)
            {
                case "TestClases":
                    GetLatestFile();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias!